# Restricting input to only certain characters works on Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

The script below is intended to allow the user to only input small letters from a-z, numbers from 0-9 and dash `-`. This works well on Chrome but on Firefox the text field doesn't allow any input at all. What is going wrong?

```
$('#slug_input').keypress(function(key) {
        return((key.keyCode >= 97 && key.keyCode <= 122) || (key.keyCode >= 48 && key.keyCode <= 57) || key.keyCode == 45 );
    });
```

Comment: Use `var keyCode = key.keyCode || key.which;` and use it in `return`.

Comment: Use `pattern="[a-z0-9-]*"` attribute on `<input>`

Comment: @Tushar what is that `key.which` for ?

Comment: react on ,on('keyup'), for better key handling

Comment: @Grumpy `keyup` allowed everything to input and void by condition but when using `keypress` works correctly on chrome but not on firefox..

Comment: It is a better idea to use `input` event.

Comment: @Tushar is `pattern` attribute of HTML5 ? if so it will not work well with safari but jquery will work on all browsers,right ?

Comment: @Sumit Yes, so, both should be used. If `pattern` is not supported, it'll be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.keycode` was not supported by Firefox. Use `event.which` for firefox. Check the below code which allows alphanumerics and hyphen only.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#slug_input').keypress(function(evt) {

    var keyID = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode);
    return ((keyID >= 97 && keyID <= 122) || (keyID >= 48 && keyID <= 57) || keyID == 45);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="slug_input">
```

But as suggested by tushar, i will suggest you to use Regex Matching.

Comment: missing jquery in snippet.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi didnt get you?

Comment: @void wow ,it worked completely but its `key.charCode` instead of `evt.charCode` as `key` argument is passed on function `$('#slug_input').keypress(function(key)`

Comment: @Pete @void has used `?`  conditional statement to assign `key.keycode` to `keyID`

Comment: @void yah man I already figured what you meant though there was some mistake...I corrected it and used and it worked perfectly...see my comments above I have already mentioned the mistake and marked your answer correct...

Comment: @void Feel free to include regex in answer if you feel it'll improve answer.

Comment: @Sumit, my previous comment and before the edit that last value in the return was left as `key.keyCode` instead of `keyID`. I know what a tertiary is and wasn't commenting on that

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#slug_input').keypress(function(key) {
    return((key.which >= 97 && key.which <= 122) || (key.which >= 48 && key.which <= 57) || key.which == 45 );
});
```

Comment: This will have the opposite problem to what the OP is having at the moment